# Need to find which drives are mirrored within RAID-10 array

Tags: linux, raid, mdadm, opensuse, raid-10

I have a home media server running on openSUSE 12.2.  I'm using eight 2TB drives in a RAID-10 configuration.  I deliberately bought two different types of drives: four Seagate Barracuda Green and four Western Digital Red.  My goal is to configure the RAID such that each mirrored pair within the array will consist of dissimilar drives (ie, one Seagate drive and one WD drive).  YaST2 Partitioner unfortunately did not give me this level of choice in the structure of the array, so now I'm trying to find out what the default RAID10 structure looks like.

I do know the following:

- sdc, sdd, sde, and sdf are all WD drives
- sdg, sdh, sdi, and sdj are all Seagate drives

I chose the default 'n2' layout when creating the RAID.  My guess based upon info from these two sources is that adjacent drives are mirrored (ie, sdc==sdd, sde==sdf, etc), but I want to know for sure:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_RAID_levels#Linux_MD_RAID_10
- https://serverfault.com/questions/200725/mirrored-and-stripped-hd-drives-in-raid10

Here is the output of 'mdadm --detail /dev/md0':

> ```
> /dev/md0:
>         Version : 1.0
>   Creation Time : Sat Mar 16 12:55:11 2013
>      Raid Level : raid10
>      Array Size : 7814045696 (7452.05 GiB 8001.58 GB)
>   Used Dev Size : 1953511424 (1863.01 GiB 2000.40 GB)
>    Raid Devices : 8
>   Total Devices : 8
>     Persistence : Superblock is persistent
>
>   Intent Bitmap : Internal
>
>     Update Time : Sat Mar 16 13:09:37 2013
>           State : active, resyncing
>  Active Devices : 8
> Working Devices : 8
>  Failed Devices : 0
>   Spare Devices : 0
>
>          Layout : near=2
>      Chunk Size : 2048K
>
>   Resync Status : 1% complete
>
>            Name : aldaris:0  (local to host aldaris)
>            UUID : c6cc3943:97394500:b77d44cd:f02ed876
>          Events : 149
>
>     Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
>        0       8       33        0      active sync   /dev/sdc1
>        1       8       49        1      active sync   /dev/sdd1
>        2       8       65        2      active sync   /dev/sde1
>        3       8       81        3      active sync   /dev/sdf1
>        4       8       97        4      active sync   /dev/sdg1
>        5       8      113        5      active sync   /dev/sdh1
>        6       8      129        6      active sync   /dev/sdi1
>        7       8      145        7      active sync   /dev/sdj1
> ```

And here are the contents of /proc/mdstat:

```
Personalities : [raid10] md0 : active raid10 sdj1[7] sdi1[6] sdh1[5] sdg1[4] sdf1[3] sde1[2] sdd1[1] sdc1[0]
      7814045696 blocks super 1.0 2048K chunks 2 near-copies [8/8] [UUUUUUUU]
      [>....................]  resync =  4.8% (375163456/7814045696) finish=1206.5min speed=102751K/sec
      bitmap: 57/59 pages [228KB], 65536KB chunk

unused devices: <none>
```

So my questions are:

1. How do I tell which drives are mirrors of each other?
2. Is there a way to change this, or should I just swap the wires
   around (since that will swap the drive letters) and then rebuild the
   RAID?

Thanks in advance.

---

Tangential note, for anyone wants to know my reasoning for doing this is:
Drives of the same model and batch, operated under similar usage loads, uptime, and temperature have little systematic variation, and differences in time to failure between drives will be primarily driven by random variation in the manufacturing process.  This increases the risk of multiple drives dying at once.  By purchasing drives not just from different batches but completely different manufacturers, I am introducing systematic variation into my array, thus influencing which drives will fail at similar times.

Comment: Home media servers are off-topic for ServerFault. That said, you clearly put some effort into this and I'm going to flag it for migration to [unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @AndrewB, why is that?

Comment: It's a very interesting question and the reasoning behind is so well understood. You don't have to change wires since just to specify disk in when (re-)creating RAID is much more simpler.

Comment: @poige This falls under [*anything in a home setting*](http://serverfault.com/faq#questions). I tried to make it clear that I considered the question adequately researched despite this.

Comment: If I were to wildly speculate, then I would guess that you could look at the `RaidDevice` column.  It might be as simple as (0,1),(2,3),(4,5),(6,7).  That would make me assume that you need to make RaidDevice line up like WD/Sea/WD/Sea/etc...  But I am not 100% certain about that.

Comment: Contents of section [Raid10](http://linux.die.net/man/4/md) suggests that blocks are "arbitrarily" scattered, meaning that no one drive is an exact replica of no other drive. Perhaps I misunderstood. To get a fine grained control over "reflected" data, I think you have to manually create four raid1 volumes each consisting of a wd/seagate pair, and then strip those four volumes into raid0. But that is suboptimal because total loss could be caused by only 2 drives.

Answer (score 10):

Recent versions of `mdadm` show this right in the details of the array. Example from `mdadm v3.3 - 3rd September 2013`

```
 $ mdadm --detail /dev/md1

/dev/md1:
        Version : 1.1
  Creation Time : Tue Aug 23 11:45:41 2016
     Raid Level : raid10
     Array Size : 3864803328 (3685.76 GiB 3957.56 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 1932401664 (1842.88 GiB 1978.78 GB)
   Raid Devices : 4
  Total Devices : 4
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

  Intent Bitmap : Internal

    Update Time : Fri Aug 26 09:39:28 2016
          State : active
 Active Devices : 4
Working Devices : 4
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

         Layout : near=2
     Chunk Size : 512K

           Name : px4-300r-THXOAP:1  (local to host px4-300r-THXOAP)
           UUID : 5ee06437:83dfdb64:808feaa2:5d57b1e6
         Events : 620

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       4       8       50        0      active sync set-A   /dev/sdd2
       1       8       34        1      active sync set-B   /dev/sdc2
       2       8       18        2      active sync set-A   /dev/sdb2
       3       8        2        3      active sync set-B   /dev/sda2
```

Note the denotation `set-A` or `set-B`. In the above case, `sdd` and `sdb` can fail together without data loss.
It is possible this data is not available while the array is rebuilding though.

Comment: I found [another conversation](https://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=1514203) about this, that seems to confirm my understanding of how it works.  If I'm right, then the above post should be corrected before someone loses their entire array by removing both drives from the same set.

Comment: This answer is correct. The other post is wrong. set-A and set-B are mirrors of each other. Try reading them with dd as suggested in the below answer.

Comment: Sorry, I should have studied the other answers that suggest using dd... you're right, the above answer is correct. I made the bad assumption that it wouldn't be reliable to use dd to check this while the system is in use.  In fact, it didn't work for me on the main partitions, but since /boot was a different partition (and not getting written too), the dd trick worked great.

Comment: Can someone clarify what set-A and set-B are indicating in this case? The answer indicates that sdd and sdb can fail together. Is it also the case that sdd and sda can fail together?

Comment: @Erotemic I think of it this way: any "set-X" contains a full copy of your data. That's why `/dev/sdd2` and `/dev/sdb2` can fail together and it will be okay: you still have *another set*, which, again, is a full copy of your data. This is with RAID10 at least.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and after googling a while I didn't find a reliable answer. After giving it some thoughts, I figured that the mirrors have the same data and so we could compare some part of it.

NOTE: BE CAREFUL, IF YOU HAVE MORE THAN 2 DRIVES WITH THE SAME CHECKSUM YOU ARE PROBABLY COMPARING EMPTY DISKSPACE, CHOOSE ANOTHER OFFSET (skip option).

With this few commands, you can figure it out:

```
for disk in sda sdb sdc sdd
do
  echo -n "$disk = ";
  dd if=/dev/$disk skip=1M bs=1M count=1 2>/dev/null | md5sum;
done
```

This will output something like:

```
sda = 7c4ef0f3e0143b35e044d5d65908a3a2  -
sdb = 7c4ef0f3e0143b35e044d5d65908a3a2  -
sdc = e02f7d61ad3791bd691da5b7516928a5  -
sdd = e02f7d61ad3791bd691da5b7516928a5  -
```

Now we know that sda/sdb is one mirror and sdc/sdd another one. One of each must stay to avoid data loss.

The "dd" command is reading one time (count=1) one Megabyte (bs=1M) at one Megabyte offset from the disk start (skip=1M). Don't skip=0, because the begining of the disk contains different information. The data usually begins after 1MB.

Comment: `dd if=/dev/$disk skip=1M bs=1M count=1` didn't work for me. `dd (coreutils) 8.23` from Debian 8 (Jessie) doesn't support `skip` with a unit. Instead I used `skip=1` where `1` is relative to `bs`. Possibly a typo?

Comment: FYI If you're seeing the MD5 sum `d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e` your `dd` call fails. That is the hash of the empty string:-)

Answer (score 2):

You can always verify which are mirrors by a crude manner of comparing the data, for example:

```
# dd if=/dev/sda1 bs=1M skip=10 count=50 2> /dev/null | md5sum -
7c01afa434fc74aeddc8ec0546e4c332  -
# dd if=/dev/sdb1 bs=1M skip=10 count=50 2> /dev/null | md5sum -
1f0f8166857710d555cb35db4a23891a  -
# dd if=/dev/sdg1 bs=1M skip=10 count=50 2> /dev/null | md5sum -
7c01afa434fc74aeddc8ec0546e4c332  -
# dd if=/dev/sdf1 bs=1M skip=10 count=50 2> /dev/null | md5sum -
1f0f8166857710d555cb35db4a23891a  -
```

(if you don't get any matches, you may need to increase *skip=*, as you're not skipping over RAID superblocksl; and if you get same md5sum for more than 2 disks, you may need to increase *count=*, as you're probably reading and m5summing zeros - to prevent that you should put some data on the raid first, otherwise they might be full of zeroes)

As for the swapping wires around, you don't need to do that - mdadm should create raid with devices as specified on command line in *mdadm --create*, so you would just specify drives in different order on command line.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about a real raid 10 array (1+0 striped mirroring)

```
sdc/sdg = md0 raid1 2TB |
sdd/sdh = md1 raid1 2TB |_  md4 raid0 8TB
sde/sdi = md2 raid1 2TB |
sdf/sdj = md3 raid1 2TB |
```

**1. Create your 4 raid1 arrays:**

```
mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level=1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/{sdc,sdg}
mdadm --create /dev/md1 --level=1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/{sdd,sdh}
mdadm --create /dev/md2 --level=1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/{sde,sdi}
mdadm --create /dev/md3 --level=1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/{sdf,sdj}
```

At this time you have 4 raid 1 arrays with 2TB space on each,

**2. Let's assemble them!**

```
mdadm --create /dev/md4 --run --level=0 --raid-devices=4 /dev/md{0,1,2,3}
```

*--run* options is usefull because some components are active in another array

**3. Adapt your mdadm.conf file**

You may need (depending of your configuration) to adapt this file to reflect changes about our new array (/dev/md4).

**4. Enjoy..**
Your new DIY raid10 array!

Comment: No, he's talking about linux's mdadm raid10 personality. I believe your answer doesn't apply (although, to be fair, it does give the OP an alternative to achieve what he needs to do)

Comment: The performance and supported features differ as well.

Answer (score 0):

Run "mdadm --examine device" on each component device (i.e. /dev/sda1, /dev/sdb1, etc.). The information there should help you determine which components are each others' mirror.